# How to analyse a windows service dump

Tags: c#, web-services, service, dump

Im in trouble. 
I have made a windowsservice that connect to differenct webservices.
In this process data is collected and saved in our MSSQL database.

Now when my service has been running for about 8-10 hours, then it suddently dumps due to System.OutOfMemoryException Stack.
How am I able/supposed to analyse what goes wrong?

I hope that one or more of you clever guys, can help me - because Im stuck with a unhappy boss :-( .
If you think - or know how - that I can deliver more relevant information, then please let me know.

Dump from eventviewer below:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name=".NET Runtime" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1026</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-06-09T14:52:16.000000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>1941389</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>XYZ1234.intern.xyz.dk</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>Program: windowsservice.exe Framework-version: v4.0.30319    Description: This proces was terminated due to an unhandled exception.   Exceptioninformation: System.OutOfMemoryException Stak: ved System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItemHelper(System.Threading.WaitCallback, System.Object, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, Boolean) ved System.Threading.ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem(System.Threading.WaitCallback, System.Object) ved   System.Threading.TimerQueue.QueueTimerCompletion(System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer) ved System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers() ved System.Threading.TimerQueue.AppDomainTimerCallback()</Data> 
 </EventData>
 </Event>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is a bosses purpose to be unhappy.. My advice is worry less about the dump and debug some code and run some events through it and see if you can find where you're not releasing memory .. its either that or at some point you amalgamate so many "still running" tasks within the app you're chewing through what you have..

Comment: `.net memory leak dump file`, as search terms, seems to find plenty of resources. Even if you limit it to just searching SO, you should find plenty of existing answers that address how to do this.